# Cognos - data item for retrieving a hard-coded data not working

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-8

I have a data item that pulls a list of static historical data for the employee headcount upon request, it is a double-nested case statement with hard-coded number for our historical data and the query looks like this:

```
CASE ([Year])       
    WHEN '2014' 
     THEN 
        (
        CASE ([Quarter])
            WHEN '01'
            THEN 
                (
                CASE ([department])
                 when 'Sales' then 100
                 when 'HR' then 15
                 When 'Engineering' Then 25
```

........ 
 and so on.

The weird thing, everything works except for quarter 3 of 2013. When I try to get the data for this particular quarter, it gives me the right number, but divided by 82.2536.   There is nothing in the code that prompts it to do this.

In fact, the number 82.2536 also never appears anywhere in the code.

Additionally, this error only recently surfaced after we transition from Cognos 8 to Cognos 10. Although it worked fine under Cognos 10 for a while.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Try grabbing the generated SQL for the query in question and running it directly against the data source using a client-specific query tool (e.g. DB2 Data Studio). Do you get the same number? If so, analyze the SQL to see if you can determine the cause.